# How to find a minimal polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, minimal-polynomials

I need to find minimal polynomial of $\alpha = \sqrt 2 + \sqrt [3] 3 $ over $\mathbb Q$ and prove that my result is minimal polynomial. How do I do that?

Comment: see  here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422233/how-to-find-a-minimal-polynomial-field-theory

Comment: [Constructing a degree 4 rational polynomial satisfying $f(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}) = 0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/359054/25554) asks the same question about a very similar number and my answer there describes a straightforward general algorithm.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way to *find* the minimal polynomial is to start with the supposition that
$$
x - \left( \sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{3} \right) = 0
$$
then move the $\sqrt[3]{3}$ to the right side of the equality and cube, getting
$$
x^2 + 6x - \sqrt{2} \left( 3x^2+2 \right) = 3
$$
Now isolate the terms involving $\sqrt{2}$ on the right and square, getting
(after some grouping of terms)
$$
x^6 - 6x^4 - 6x^3 + 12x^2 - 36x + 1 = 0
$$
from which you read off the minimal polynomial.

It is easy to verify that this is a polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\Bbb{Q}$.  To prove minimality you need to invoke the fact that $\gcd(2,3) = 1$, which implies that a minimal polynomial of a square root and a cube root of two numbers sharing no common factors must be of degree at least $6$.

Comment: >To prove minimality you need to invoke the fact that gcd(2,3)=1, which implies that a minimal polynomial of a sqare root and a cube root off two numbers sharing no common factors must be of degree at least 6.

Comment: Could you explain that?

Comment: Very handy technique ! +1

Answer (score 4):

It can be done in two steps:

$\left(\alpha - \sqrt{2}\right)^3 = \left(\sqrt[3]{3}\right)^3 = 3$, then you get:

$p(\alpha)\sqrt{2} = q(\alpha)$, and square both sides again:

$2p(\alpha)^2 - q(\alpha)^2=0$, where $p(\alpha), q(\alpha)$ are integer-coefficient polynomials in $\alpha$, and this is the minimal polynomial you seek.